# Why can't I call a reference to document.getElementById I've stored in a variable?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser

While I'm at work, I'll write little snippets of JS to explore the language proper, not using any frameworks. However, since I'm lazy, I'll keep a reference to `document.getElementById` by storing it in a variable:

```
var grab = document.getElementById;
var foo = grab('some_id');
var bar = grab('some_other_id');
```

This has always worked in IE7/8, but I tried it back home on Firefox and it didn't like the shortcut. Now, it works when I wrap it up in a function and close over the argument:

```
var grab = function (some_id) {  
    return document.getElementById(some_id);  
};
```

but I don't understand why I need to do that; in Firefox I can throw around references to user-defined functions and it doesn't complain:

```
var foo = function(x) {
    alert(x);
};
var bar = foo;
foo('foo'); // alerts 'foo'
bar('bar'); // alerts 'bar'
```

Why can't I call a reference to document.getElementById I've stored in a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about `this` value. I've created a test case on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pomeh/mPRZR/ to show you the problem.

When you do `var foo = document.getElementById("...");`, this value of `this` inside the function is the `document` object.

When you do `var grab = document.getElementById; var foo = grab("...");` you're executing the `getElementById` in a **global context**. In this case, the value of `this` inside the function is the global object, and not the `document` object.

I hope that's clear for you :) Look at the example and logged values.

Comment: Ah, so is it another case of IE polluting the global namespace? If so, what exactly are they putting there that causes the faulty code to work?

Comment: Well, I don't think so. I think the problem come from different ways of handling `host object` (`document` is one of them) on IE and on other browsers. I'm not 100% sure of that, but it's the best explanation I've got from my knowledge right now :)

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
var grab = document.getElementById.bind( document );
```

So, you use the `bind` function method to explicitly set the context for your `grab` function.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/E2tvB/

*(Note: you'll need to polyfill `bind` to achieve cross-browser compatibility.)*

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this to short my codes. And as this far, I have never found any problem with my method.

```js
var grab=function (x){return document.getElementById(x);};

grab("par").textContent="This is textContent of paragraph AFTER changed by javascript";
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p id="par">This is textContent of paragraph BEFORE changed by javascript</p>
</body>
</html>
```